# Passing Javascript Object to html, then back to javascript

Tags: javascript, html, object

I have a javascript function that uses jquery to append a textbox that has an onkeypress property that calls another javascript function. My problem is that when I try to pass my contentItem object to the javascript method, it is not defined when called inside that method.

Here is my jquery code that appends the javascript function (it is dynamic and named whatever the value of checkMethodName is).

```
$(element).append('<div id="' + id + 'div" style="position: relative;display:none; cursor: default"><p id="' + id + 'lbl"> ' + initStatusMessage + '</p><input type="text" name="' + id + '" id="' + id + '" onkeypress="return ' + checkMethodName + '(event, ' + id + ', contentItem)" /></div>');
```

I have also tried this(and I end up getting a syntax error, unexpected identifier):

```
$(element).append('<div id="' + id + 'div" style="position: relative;display:none; cursor: default"><p id="' + id + 'lbl"> ' + initStatusMessage + '</p><input type="text" name="' + id + '" id="' + id + '" onkeypress="return ' + checkMethodName + '(event, ' + id + ', ' + contentItem + ')" /></div>');
```

I have a feeling that something is going wrong because it is plain text, but the event object gets passed correctly...

This is the method that is being called, which cannot see the contentItem object:

```
function checkValidAuditor(e, id, contentItem) {
var statusmessage = $('#' + id.id + 'lbl');
if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/ApplicationData.svc/Employees?$filter=AuthCode eq '"+ id.value +"'",
        dataType: 'json', 
        success: function (json) {
            if (json.value[0] == null) {
                statusmessage.text("ERROR: Unauthorized.");
                statusmessage.css({ "color": "red", "font-size": "20px" });
            } else {
                if (json.value[0].Employee_EmployeeType == 2) {
                    statusmessage.text("Successful Authentication");
                    statusmessage.css({ "color": "green", "font-size": "20px" });
                    contentItem.screen.JobData.JobOperator.value = id.value;
                    $.unblockUI();
                } else {
                    statusmessage.text("ERROR: Auditors only. Please scan again.");
                    statusmessage.css({ "color": "red", "font-size": "20px" });
                }
            }
        },
        error: function (e) {
            alert(e);
            console.log(e);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

}

This is the full function that the jquery append lives in:

```
function createBarcodeAuth(element, contentItem, id, type, autostart) {
//Set Initial Value
var initVal;
var initStatusMessage;
var checkMethodName;
if (contentItem.value == null) {
    initVal = "";
} else {
    initVal = contentItem.value;
}
contentItem.value = initVal;

switch (type) {
    case "auditor":
        initStatusMessage = "Please scan Auditor's barcode.";
        checkMethodName = "checkValidAuditor";
        break;
    case "operator":
        initStatusMessage = "Please scan Operator's barcode.";
        checkMethodName = "checkValidOperator";
        break;
    case "setup":
        initStatusMessage = "Please scan Setup's barcode.";
        checkMethodName = "checkValidSetup";
        break;
    case "job":
        initStatusMessage = "Please scan Job's barcode.";
        checkMethodName = "checkValidJob";
        break;
    case "default":
        break;
}
$(element).append('<div id="' + id + 'div" style="position: relative;display:none; cursor: default"><p id="' + id + 'lbl"> ' + initStatusMessage + '</p><input type="text" style="position: absolute; top: 9999px; name="' + id + '" id="' + id + '" onkeypress="return ' + checkMethodName + '(event, ' + id + ', ' + contentItem + ')" /></div>');

var lock = window.setInterval(function () {
    document.getElementById(id).focus();
}, 200);

var barcodeauth = $("#" + id);

barcodeauth.on("change", function () {
    contentItem.value = barcodeauth.val();
});

if (autostart) {
    $.blockUI({
        message: $('#' + id + 'div'),
        css: {
            width: '275px',
            height: '75px'
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: contentItem is being passed as a reference to a global property that doesn't appear to exist. Where is it defined?

Comment: I have added the full function that the contentItem exists in.

Comment: contentItem doesn't appear to be created within that function either, it's just a parameter.

Comment: This is a Lightswitch application. The contentItem is created by lightswitch and passed to my function. It works and exists inside the createBarcodeAuth function, but not once I try to pass it to the checkValid method.

Comment: Right, but contentItem clearly isn't global, which is required for it to be accessible in an inline attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is a loss of scope. Events created using inline attribute on elements are always executed in the global scope, therefore they only have access to globally available properties. The best way to solve your problem would be to **stop using inline attributes for events**.

```
$(element).append('<div id="' + id + 'div" style="position: relative;display:none; cursor: default"><p id="' + id + 'lbl"> ' + initStatusMessage + '</p><input type="text" name="' + id + '" id="' + id + '" /></div>')
    .find("div:last input").on("keypress",function(event){
        checkMethodName(event, id, contentItem);
    });
```